# Category attribute frontend model

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, attributes, catalog

I've created an attribute called `hero_text_background` in the `catalog_category` entity. With this i'm looking to update the `frontend_model` property to render some HTML for the frontend.

To test the frontend model works, i've updated the `frontend_model` column with the correct class group id in the `eav_attribute` table for the attribute. And expected to see the return value for the getValue method i've created in the class.

In my themes `catalog/category/view.phtml` i'm calling the attribute from the category object (`$_category->getHeroTextBackground()`) this returns the raw attribute value from the database and not through the "frontend model" class.

Do i have to pass my attribute through a method to get the rendered output? Have I configured my attribute wrong?

**UPDATE**
Original install script, for development i've updated the `is_html_allowed_on_front` and `backend_model`

```
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'default_setup');

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute(
    $installer->getEntityTypeId(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY),
    'hero_text_background',
    array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Hero Text Background',
        'input' => 'select',
        'source' => 'bennoislost_heroheaders/catalog_category_attribute_source_hero',
        'default' => Bennoislost_HeroHeaders_Model_Catalog_Category_Attribute_Source_Hero::HB_DEFAULT,
        'required' => false,
        'sort_order' => 0,
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'group' => 'Display Settings',
    )
);
```

**UPDATE 2**

The following snippet indeed call's the correct class:

```
$_heroTextBackground = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'hero_text_background')
    ->getFrontend()
    ->getValue($_category);
```

Is there a nicer way to use this in the template file out of the box?

Comment: My attribute is part of the `catalog_category` entity not the `catalog_product` entity

Comment: Thank you with a little update the following snippit works.

`$_heroTextBackground = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'hero_text_background')->getFrontend()->getValue($_category);`

Comment: Doesn't make sense, what I wrote. I'll delete it. Glad you found a solution, feel free to post it as answer and mark it.

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will load the `frontend_model` for the attribute:

```
$_heroTextBackground = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'hero_text_background')
    ->getFrontend()
    ->getValue($_category);
```

I'm still wondering if their is a nicer / less verbose way to use this in a category template...

Comment: sadly I dont see a 'nice' way of doing this, look at `getAdditionalData` in the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes` that is doing the same thing.